# I have a cyclic executed C# function. Sometimes the exec. time of the function is exceeding the timer period. How can I pause the timer in this case?

Tags: c#, timer

In my C# windows service project I am executing a function cyclic with a timer (every 35 ms). The function is reading some values from a remote machine and therefore the executing time is changing related to the network conditions. (In most cases <30 ms but rarely >35 ms)

I have used a system timer for cyclic execution. I know that the system timers are not very accurate but I have to live with it, because I cannot change to a RTOS. In my current code I am not sure what is happening when the execution time of the function is greater then the timer period. What I assume: Before the function is completed the timer ticks again and the function is retriggered again. So my function is triggered in parallel in this case.

In order to prevent this, I want to do something like that: In the discribed case above, can I pause the timer, until the function is completed and restart it then again? I want that after the execution of the "delayed" function is finished, the function should be retriggered in 35 ms again. (Not at the next timer tick)

My Code

```
 System.Timers.Timer timer4 = new System.Timers.Timer();        
 public void InitializeTimer_4_Measuring_period()
    {
        timer4.Elapsed += new    ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent_Measuring_period);
        timer4.Interval = 35;
    }

 public void OnTimedEvent_Measuring_period(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        periodic_function(); // the execution time of this function sometimes exceeds timer period
    }
```

Comment: `if(!executing) { executing = true; periodic_function(); executing = false; }` ? (or `AtomicBoolean`)

Comment: It's unclear how you wana handle this... you wana skip and run on next tick? or you wana just run next ASAP

Comment: Similar to Selvin's suggestion: [SemaphoreSlim.Wait(0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.wait?view=net-8.0#system-threading-semaphoreslim-wait(system-int32))

Comment: @Selvin  Not excactly what I want to acchieve. In this case, the timer would not retrigger the function until the next timer tick. I want that after finishing of the delayed function, the function should be retriggered after 35ms again. So I want just shift  a little bit the timer.

Comment: In that case: [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-8.0).

Comment: @Fildor  Will it be ok when I just write     

var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(35));
while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    periodic_function()
}
I mean will the timer will delay its tick, until the function is completed? Or how will it work excactly? Read the periodictimer docu, but couldnt understand

Comment: _"The PeriodicTimer behaves like an auto-reset event, in that multiple ticks are coalesced into a single tick if they occur between calls to WaitForNextTickAsync(CancellationToken)."_ - That means: If an invocation is longer than the period, it won't fire immediately. It will ignore the skipped time and wait for the next after that. Which is most probably what you want, since it gives you an unshifted schedule of samples with just singular samples missing.

Comment: @Fildor  Last question if you allow: Yes I have got you know. And in most cases this would make more sense. But unf. in my usecase, if the periodic function takes longer then the period: 1) The timer should not tick and retrigger the function in paralllel (This part is OK with PeriodicTimer) 2) The next function should be triggered in that case as soon as the "delayed" function is finished. (Not waiting until next tick.  I mean part 1) is OK with the PeriodicTimer. How to realise part 2) in this case?

Comment: If you need both, then PeriodicTimer is probably _not_ the best solution. Maybe you need actually to roll something custom, I am afraid.